# python function - taking a string and returning it with only certain characters

Tags: python, function

sorry but i'm new to Python and have a question. How can I create a function that for example takes the string "26355" but only returns "6"? As in it will only return a value if the string given to the function has a 6 in it?
Thank you.

Comment: can you explain how 6 is coming..?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following function

```
def return_wanted_string(inp_str, wanted_str):
    return (wanted_str if wanted_str in inp_str else "Not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the approach can be -

```
def search(input_string, matching_char):
    if input_string.index(matching_char) >= 0:
        return input_string
    return None
```

Above function can be called as

```
search("26355", "6")
```

in this case it will return "26355"

Comment: Hey guys thank you for the replies, I don't know if someone has answered this but what if the string given has multiple 6's? How could I take for example the string "263396" and only return the string "66" from it?

Answer (score 0):

```
def custom_function(string_word, specific_word):
    if specific_word in string_word:
        return specific_word
    else:
        return 'Nothing Find'

In [25]: custom_function('26343','6')
Out[25]: '6'
In [26]: custom_function('2343','6')
Out[26]: 'Nothing Find'
```

This is easiest way to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way -

```
def func(input_str, input_char):
    if input_char in input_str:
        return input_char
    return None
```

- If character is found then it is returned
- If character is not found function returns None

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=filter#filter) command as follows:

```
print filter(lambda x: x == '6', '26355')
print filter(lambda x: x == '6', '263396')
```

Which would give you:

```
6
66
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work :

```
number = "123456786960"
want = "6"
"".join([i for i in number if i == want])
```